# Reverse AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior

Tags: android

I have a `ToolBar` and `Recyclerview` wrapped in a `Coordinatorlayout`. The RecyclerView is populated with messages from our api and are stacked from the bottom. (Like a chat application)

```
 //Set the layout manager
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext());
 layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
 layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
 binding.listMessages.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

I'd like to define a custom `ReverseScrollBehavior` by overriding the `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` to inverse it's behavior.
So when I scroll up, the toolbar hides and when I scroll back down (to the bottom) the toolbar shows.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:stackFromEnd="true"
    app:reverseLayout="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.rootsoft.kot.utils.ReverseScrollBehavior" />
```

I'd like to use the `ScrollingViewBehavior` for this rather then overriding the `onTouch`

**UPDATE**

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the inverse of the current `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`. Imagine having a chat application where the newest messages are starting from the bottom. When you scroll up, I want to hide the toolbar. The current situation with the AppBarLayout is when you scroll up, the toolbar is shown and when you scroll back down, it hides. 
My scrollflags are: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`

Comment: I'm just trying to do the inverse of the current ```appbar_scrolling_view_behavior```. Imagine having a chat application where the newest messages are starting from the bottom. When you scroll up, I want to hide the toolbar. The current situation with the AppBarLayout is when you scroll up, the toolbar is shown. My scrollflags are: ```app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"```

Comment: @Cheticamp I've already created a ReverseScrollBehavior extending the ```AppBarLayout.Behavior``` but I don't know which methods to override in order to achieve the effect that . I'm looking for.

Comment: I think `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` dose the same what you want. **When you scroll up, It hides the toolbar.**

Comment: @RumitPatel It depends on the context of scrolling up. I mean when the content scrolls up. so when you drag your finger from the center to the bottom, you scroll the content up, I want to hide the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method that will get the height of the screen and scroll events (up and down.) You can also toggle the visibility in the method. 
This means you will set visibility to visible in your XML and do something like:

```
    ChatButton Button;

    ChatButtton.setVisibility = View.GONE 
    ChatButton.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE
```

to handle the toggle of the visibility based on the scroll events

Comment: I know how to do it using the scroll listener. I prefer to use the ScrollingViewBehavior method.